# How can I copy a file into the subfolders of multiple directories with the same prefix?

Tags: shell, wildcards, cp

I have a file called "foo.txt" in my current directory.  This directory also has folders named *myfolder1*, *myfolder2*, etc...  Each of these folders has a subfolder called "constant".

I want to copy "foo.txt" into *myfolder1/constant*, *myfolder2/constant*, etc...

I tried to do this with the command:

```
cp foo.txt myfolder*/constant
```

This resulted in the error:

```
cp: omitting directory `myfolder1/constant'
cp: omitting directory `myfolder2/constant'
etc...
```

Is there a way I can copy a file into the sub-folder of multiple directories with the same prefix (in this case, the prefix being 'myfolder')?

Answer (score 2):

When `cp` gets more than two arguments, the last one is taken as the destination directory and the other ones the files to copy there.

`cp` doesn't know that you used a wildcard: wildcards are expanded by the shell before the command sees them. So even if `cp` had some kind of multi-target capability, it couldn't use this syntax.

You'd need a loop. In Bourne-like shells:

```
(ret=0
for dir in myfolder*/constant/; do
  cp foo.txt "$dir" || ret=$?
done
exit "$ret")
```

The `$ret` business is to report any `cp` failure in the exit status in the end.